# Are OS installations on a disk linked to a system?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd

I have a MBP17 with an SSD (Sierra) which I want to switch with my husband's MBP13 for work related reasons.

Would taking out the SSD (OS and files intact) from the MBP17 and placing it in the MBP13 without re-installing anything render any problems? Meaning is the harddrive linked to an installation in any way, leading me to have to re-install Mac on the SSD before I can use the MBP13?

Would it matter that the MBP13 is still on El Capitan and the MBP17 on Sierra?

Comment: Usually the pure OS isn't linked to the hardware. But the hardware of the 17" (2,5" SSD) may not fit in the 13" (e.g. PCIe card). Also: some software licenses are linked to hardware (e.g MAC or the serial number of your Mac). So please add the MacBook Pro identifiers (e.g. MacBookPro11,1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem. I have done similar things both with an external disk and an internal disk. The first boot may take a very long time, but it is working — leave it to do its thing. Of course, double check your backups before performing something like this.

Comment: The 2,5" SSD of the 17" MBP doesn't even fit into a 13" (Mid-2013 and later)

Comment: @klanomath The question wasn't about the hardware connectivity. An enclosure is a perfect way for this to work.

Comment: True: the header and parts of the body ("...placing it in the MBP13...") of the question are quite different